# Parameterize Azure DataFactory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, parameterization

I am copying data from Azure SQLdb to Azure data lake, is there a way to fetch Blob information like blobname, blobkey, and container to parameterize Sink dataset properties.

Comment: Using GetMetaData Activity you will be able to fetch the details, as generally in sink, if we give dataset parameter in container name, if the container does not exists it create contain/directory and store the data. May you specify more about goal.

Answer (score 0):

The `Get Metadata Activity` in Azure Data Factory may be used to get metadata for any data. The metadata from the Get Metadata action can be used in conditional expressions to conduct validation or consumed in later activities.

> **NOTE:** When using Get Metadata activity against a folder, make sure you have
> LIST/EXECUTE permission to the given folder.

To get the necessary information, you may provide the following metadata types in the Get Metadata action field list. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-get-metadata-activity#metadata-options).

As generally in sink, if we give dataset parameter in container name, if the container does not exists it create contain/directory and store the data. May you specify more about goal.